# Additional (internal) email recipient without tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I recently received the request that when sending e-mails, different internal employees always want to receive the final newsletter at the same time as the normal recipients.

Example:
We have different dataextensions depending on the country. Depending on the country, other internal employees want to be informed. If we send to the USA, then Gortonington must also receive the newsletter, if we send to Australia, then Eliot Harper must also receive the e-mail.

The problem is that adding these internal employees to the dataextension would affect the results of the tracking and would also lead to distorted tracking results.

Hence my question:
Is it possible to add additional email recipients who receive an email from the sending process without distorting the tracking?

My current best idea would be to add these contacts to the dataextension and set their "DoNotTrack" value to Yes. Would this cause all important system tables not to count these contacts? So for all dataviews _Open, (especially!) _Send, _Click, .... 
Is there another functionality that is already included in the Salesforce standard? Possibly a separate window during the sending process, if you would activate BCC and CC e-mails? Or would this lead to a large number of e-mails being sent to these BCC/CC e-mails?

Comment: are you looking at just one of the newsletters being sent to the employee, or one of each of the emails sent in the job also going to the employee?

Comment: Just one newsletter to the employee

Comment: Really the least complicated way to do it is to add in your reporting queries something like `WHERE domain != 'mycompany.com'` or similar and just include them in the sending audience or in a separate seed DE. Otherwise you are likely looking at a pretty complex process that would need to be repeated for each send.

Comment: The DoNotTrack feature unfortunately distorts your tracking as subscribers are still included in the send count. This causes all of the standard KPIs to be skewed. The question is: how do your send processes look like and which reporting features can you use? If you work with send flow and user initiated sends I totally agree with Gortonington regarding separate audience data extensions. If you also send through journeys or triggered sends it becomes way more complicated because both rely on a single entry source.